# Integrating Apple Signin in Xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, swift

How can I get access to ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider - Apple Sign In library in Xcode 10.3? I know it is available in Xcode 11 but my app breaks for Xcode 11 and up.

Comment: sorry, you can't, apple sig in only works in Xcode 11

Comment: @AndresGomez That should really be the answer.